# Is it possible to know the last time my iPhone was online?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone was stolen about two months ago, and the company wants to know the date which I lost it.

Is it possible to recover information to the last time it was turned on?

Comment: your phone company can tell you that.

Answer (score 2):

Go to [iCloud - Find My iPhone](https://www.icloud.com/#find), and select your device. You can also see where it is right now, and you can lock and erase it.

What's required though is that you have to had iCloud set up before it got stolen.

Comment: This method does not seem to work anymore

Comment: I used it just now and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't show where the phone was last if it's been offline more than 24 hrs.

(I wonder why?)